# NextJS App Crashing within Docker With No Logs

Tags: docker, logging, next.js

I'm trying to run a NextJS app in a docker container. I'm using Prisma to connect to my database and NextAuth for OAuth.

If I run the app locally, I am able to successfully login (i.e., I can run through the whole flow as expected).

However, if I run it in the docker container, I'm getting errors as soon as I hit my `pages/api/auth[...nextAuth].ts` route.

The only logs I seem to be able to get are:

```
docker-crud-next-1      | wait  - compiling /api/auth/[...nextauth] (client and server)...
docker-crud-next-1      | event - compiled client and server successfully in 5.9s (610 modules)
docker-crud-next-1 exited with code 0
```

I've tried following the [debugger docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging#server-side-code), but am not able to get it to work within the docker container?

I've also tried running the app manually from within the container, but same situation - the app just dies and there are no logs to look at.

I.e., I create the container, then open an interactive shell and manually run the start commands. No improvement from a logs perspective. ,

I *think* it might be the prisma client ([here](https://github.com/stephencweiss/docker-crud/pull/3/files#diff-38713b428bb68c8d3a96e6f420b73df08b7b39f067b1af5fb1822ee4f4c8157dR6))... but I'm at a loss to figure out *what* is causing the app to crash.

So, questions:

1. What's the better way to get logs so I can figure out *why* it's crashing?
2. Any idea why it might work locally but not in the container?

I'm on Mac 13.1 on with an Intel (not M1/2 chip).
My understanding is that I'm using a Debian base for my docker container (though, that's probably question 3 -- how can I interrogate the image I'm using since it's based on Microsoft's Typescript Node image)

Answer (score 1):

The issue *appears* to have been related to the base image I have been using.

I missed a disclaimer when porting a project from a different machine (an M1 mac) onto this one (an intel based Mac) that the image I was using reserves the `-bullseye` variant for M1 ([source](https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/blob/main/src/typescript-node/devcontainer-template.json#L12)).

Moving to the base image *without* a variant worked:

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node as base
```

or using a the even more basic `node:18-alpine`.

Interestingly, trying to tag the `typescripte-node` image with a variant of `18` did **not** seem to work:

```yaml
ARG VARIANT="18"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-${VARIANT} as base
```

Either way, I now have a working app and Next isn't crashing. I would still *love* someone to help me understand what dependency was crashing and even better *how* I could have detected it because my logs were still totally bare.